# Gitlab: How to send a message to a user that is requesting access

Tags: gitlab

How I can message a user that is requesting access to a public group in GitLab - we have the policy of having a chat with these people and I haven't found a solution to message them. I have also seen this question being raised in the forum ([gitlab forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-send-a-message-to-user/5818)) but no answer was given.

I also raised the issue on the [support forum](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/3912).

Comment: I don't think there is anything existing (yet). But using the API to fetch all group and project access requests and send an email should be doable. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/access_requests.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct messaging feature that I know of (GitLab 11.2.3, August 2018) which would be integrated with a Group Access Request.

What you can do, for instance, is using the [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/access_requests.html) to list the request, and then the [User API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#for-admin) to get their email.

Comment: I assume this only works if one hosts the GitLab instance himself so he has the admin rights to access the mail? The user information that is publicly available doesn't include the mail ... it's very hard to maintain access requests without this feature :-(

Comment: @MaximilianSchulz agreed. Since I am admin of my GitLab instance, I might have missed that limitation.

Comment: Hello @VonC is there any update about the direct messaging feature on gitlab?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Not to my knowledge, no. The discussion was continued in [issue 30299](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/30299), for GitLab 11.9, March 2019.